# How to resize model in WPF 3d?

Tags: wpf, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

How to resize and change width Model3D?
Used helix tollkit, but can't resize model after load from 3ds.

**Update**

I load model.

```
Model3DGroup group = imp.Load("Models/model.3ds");
modelView.Content = group;
```

I see model. Need change only width or only height.

Comment: Could you please narrow down your question? also appreciated if you could share some of your code.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Input%20gestures) information?

Comment: General 3d knowledge: You will need to specify a scale matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need used ScaleTransform3D.

```
double width = 10;
double height = 10;
var group = Model as Model3DGroup;
foreach (var el in group.Children)
{
    var t = el as GeometryModel3D;
    t.Transform = new ScaleTransform3D(1, width / 10, height / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Transform property of the Model3DGroup:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.model3d.transform(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.model3d.transform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
In your case a [scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.scaletransform3d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would do.